# What is the formal / legal protocol that protects a client from their patent attorney stealing their invention?

Tags: attorney

I have asked this question before and I was told that this simply does not happen.

But nevertheless, is there a protocol that legally accomplishes this?

Comment: Other than you sue them, report them to the bar and get them disbarred? Do you have even one example of a patent attorney doing this?

Comment: What Eric said and you can ask them to sign an NDA but no attorney I have met will sign one and I have heard a few say that they will not take on anyone as a client who tries to push them to sign an NDA. You are going to have to trust a few people to keep their word and honor their obligations - your patent practitioner is one of them. Also, this is  hard to hear but, statistically speaking your idea is unlikely to be worth the risk to steal.

Comment: But if nothing is signed, what basis do I have to sue the lawyer? If I reveal my idea to any ordinary person without signing anything then they are free to legally steal my idea. What distinguishes a lawyer from an ordinary person that allows me to sue the lawyer without having to sign any contract?

Comment: I believe lawyers have codes of ethics or else they risk disbarment. Client confidentiality is one of them, I believe.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-patent-attorneys-steal-your-idea-before-they-help-you-patent-it

Comment: So they could be disbarred, but I still would not have any basis to sue.

Comment: Of course you have a basis to sue. Not having an agreement not to steal does not mean you give permission to steal.

Comment: But it's not legally stealing because I don't own the idea until a patent is filed.

Comment: Your rights have not been perfected until a patent is issued, but the concept of the invention is, essentially, a trade secret at the point you talk to a patent attorney. You own that. Also, state bars may be slow to disbar one of their own, but the USPTO OED (Office of Enrollment and Discipline) is not a panel of peers and can relatively quickly strip a patent attorney of the right to be a *patent* attorney.